# constants in /initializers folder on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, constants

I have in the directory `/config/initializers/constants_data.rb` following line:

```
ADM = User.find_by_name('admin').id
```

This is working me on localhost, but when I deploy the app to Heroku, I get the **Application Error Error H10 (App crashed)**.

How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely your admin user doesn't exist.
In this case, you should always provide a fallback.

```
ADM = User.find_or_create_by_name('admin').id
```

instead of

```
ADM = User.find_by_name('admin').id
```